# Is it possible to write a functional pointer which accepts another functional pointer in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers

so I have been learning about functional pointers and I had this question, not to tease anyone or in need of it but just out of curiosity. Im concerned with the definition of the such a functional pointer.

Comment: Do you mean "pointer to function"?

Comment: Do you talk about a pointer to funtion what has paramater as pointer to function?

Comment: If your question is about C as in the title, then please don't use the C++ tag.  They are different languages.  I removed it for you.  If you want to know about C++ as well, ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem doing something like that. Imagine you want to write different sorting algorithms, based on swapping of elements (`swap1`, `swap2`, ...). You write different functions to swap different elements, and you write different sorting algorithms (`sort1(<collection_to_sort>, &<swapping_function>`, `sort2(<collection_to_sort>, &<swapping_function>`, ...).

You can then call the different sorting algorithms, based on the different swapping functions.